# Make [off-topic] on-topic

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Here in Meta IPS, we have [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)

[off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) has only 10 questions, while [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) has 40 questions. Thus, it makes sense to merge [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) to [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

What do you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Done.

I haven't seen [on-topic](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) or [allowed-questions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) show up here (yet), but if they do, they should be merged, too.